# Set/replace $this variable in PHP

Tags: php, class, this

Is there a way to set or modify the variable `$this` in PHP? In my case, I need to call an anonymous function where `$this` refers to a class that is not necessarily the class that made ​​the call.

Pseudo-**example**:

```
function test() { 
    echo $this->name;
}

$user = new stdclass;
$user->name = "John Doe";

call_user_func(array($user, "test"));
```

**Note**: this will generate an error, because, in fact, the function expects an array containing an object and a method that exists in this object, and not any method of global scope.

Comment: **PHP is not JavaScript :)** And that's a good thing. *(PHP is not C++. And that's a bad thing.)* --- so no `.call` or `.apply` here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not try setting the function definition to accept an object as a parameter? For example:

```
function test($object) {
    if (isset($object->name)) // Make sure that the name property you want to reference exists for the class definition of the object you're passing in.
        echo $object->name;
    }
}

$user = new stdclass;
$user->name = "John Doe";

test($user); // Simply pass the object into the function.
```

The variable $this, when used in a class definition, refers to the object instance of the class. Outside of a class definition (or in a static method definition), variable $this has no special meaning. When you attempt to use $this outside of the OOP pattern, it loses meaning and call_user_func(), which relies on the OOP pattern, will not work in the way that you've attempted.

If you're using functions in a non-OOP way (like global functions), the function is not tied to any class/object and should be written in a non-OOP way (passing in data or otherwise using globals).

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [bind](http://www.php.net/manual/en/closure.bind.php) method on a closure object to change the meaning of `this` in a particular context. Note this functionality became available in PHP 5.4.

Official Description

> Duplicates a closure with a specific bound object and class scope

```
  class TestClass {
       protected $var1 = "World";
  }
  $a = new TestClass();

  $func = function($a){ echo  $a." ".$this->var1; };
  $boundFunction = Closure::bind($func, $a, 'TestClass');

  $boundFunction("Hello");

  // outputs Hello World
```

An alternative to this syntax it to use the bindTo method of an instance of a closure (anonymous function)

```
  class TestClass {
       protected $var1 = "World";
  }
  $a = new TestClass();

  $func = function($a){ echo  $a." ".$this->var1; };
  $boundFunction = $func->bindTo($a, $a);

  $boundFunction("Hello");

  // outputs Hello World
```

In your example the relevant code would be

```
$test = function() {
    echo $this->name;
};

$user = new stdclass;
$user->name = "John Doe";

$bound = $test->bindTo($user, $user);
call_user_func($bound);
```

Comment: Don't forget to mention it's `PHP 5.4+`.